# Modern CMake Cross Compiling to AArch64 with Sysroots

Tags: cmake, sysroot

Consider the following example project_(CMakeLists.txt):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

project(CCL LANGUAGES C CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
find_package(ZLIB)
find_package(PNG)
find_library(MATH_LIBRARY m)
pkg_search_module(OpenEXR OpenEXR)
add_executable(main main.cpp)
if (MATH_LIBRARY)
  target_link_libraries(main PUBLIC ${MATH_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << "Hello, sin()" << std::sin(30) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I want to compile this project with the following CMake toolchain
(aarch64-toolchain.cmake):

```
# Cross-compilation system information.
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR aarch64)

# The sysroot contains all the libraries we might need to link against and
# possibly headers we need for compilation.
set(CMAKE_SYSROOT /var/lib/schroot/chroots/ubuntu-focal-arm64)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${CMAKE_SYSROOT})
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE aarch64-linux-gnu)

# Install path when SYSROOT is read-only.
# set(CMAKE_STAGING_PREFIX aarch64-staging)

# Set the compilers for C, C++ and Fortran.
set(GCC_TRIPLE "aarch64-linux-gnu")
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${GCC_TRIPLE}-gcc-10 CACHE FILEPATH "C compiler")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${GCC_TRIPLE}-g++-10 CACHE FILEPATH "C++ compiler")
set(CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER ${GCC_TRIPLE}-gfortran CACHE FILEPATH "Fortran compiler")

# Automatically use the cross-wrapper for pkg-config when available.
set(PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE aarch64-linux-gnu-pkg-config CACHE FILEPATH "pkg-config executable")

# Set the architecture-specific compiler flags.
set(ARCH_FLAGS "-mcpu=cortex-a53+crc+simd")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_INIT ${ARCH_FLAGS})
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_INIT ${ARCH_FLAGS})
set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_INIT ${ARCH_FLAGS})

# Don't look for programs in the sysroot (these are ARM programs, they won't run
# on the build machine).
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)

# Only look for libraries, headers and packages in the sysroot, don't look on
# the build machine.
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)

set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE arm64)
```

Where the sysroot (/var/lib/schroot/chroots/ubuntu-focal-arm64) was setup using:

```
name=ubuntu-focal
mk-sbuild --arch=arm64 --skip-proposed --skip-updates --skip-security --name=${name} focal
su - $USER
mk-sbuild --arch=arm64 --skip-proposed --skip-updates --skip-security --name=${name} focal
```

Configuration-wise, this works fine, however when I try to build this project
`find_library` 'correctly' finds the **wrong** `libm.so` library:

```
$ cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../aarch-toolchain.cmake ..
$ make
Scanning dependencies of target main
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/var/lib/schroot/chroots/ubuntu-focal-arm64/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so', needed by 'main'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

Looking into the sysroot itself, the library is correctly found, but obviously,
it is a symlink to a file local to the sysroot, not the host:

```
$ ls -hal /var/lib/schroot/chroots/ubuntu-focal-arm64/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   32 Apr 14  2020 libm.so -> /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
```

It seems to me that CMake is picking up the wrong library (find_library should
really be using the compiler libraries first), so I guess that my toolchain-file
is written incorrectly somehow. How should it be changed to correctly find the
math library, without changing the sysroot or project itself?

(Also, please note that this is an example project to illustrate the problem. I still need to be able to search the sysroot for packages.)

---

### Edits

As requested in the comments, the end state should be a proper aarch64 binary
("main"). Essentially, the build commands below should succeed both with and
without the toolchain, and should yield a functional binary (although, the
aarch64 one naturally only work inside the sysroot).

```
$ mkdir -p host-build && cd host-build && cmake .. && make 
$ mkdir -p device-build && cd device-build && cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../aarch64-toolchain.cmake .. && make
```

Comment: Please clarify (in an example) what you wish to achieve i.e. you showed the current state but not the desired state., so I can better understand the issue. I'm slightly confused by what you wrote here.

Comment: Added as requested. Essentially: The build should work both with, and without the toolchain, and should produce a binary in both cases.

Comment: Maybe I need to clarify more what I don't understand: `/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6` is the library you wish to be found when using the toolchain file? What I'm trying to understand is what libraries are the "correct ones" for the toolchain build.

Comment: I guess sort of? The problem is that when you create a sysroot using `mk-sbuild`, all libraries are symlinks inside that root filesystem relative to the sysroot, not the host, so during cross-compilation those links are 'invalid' (but valid once you `chroot` into it). Yet, cmake still picks them up, generating the errors seen here

Comment: ahh perfect I think I get it now. I will return to this question once I'm at a computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TLDR: There is no easy way, as far as I know.

Your toolchain file is fine, it's the symlinks that are bad and they should ideally be relative and not absolute if you wish to use it for building. Below I mention a few options and explain the issue. This is all based on my experience with cross-compiling. Perhaps someone knows more.

---

There isn't anything wrong with your toolchainfile. From my perspective it is configured correctly. This is an issue as you pointed out with the symlinks being relative to your created rootfs and not absolute to the host machine **but they are presented as absolute**.

IIRC there is not much you can do here.

I'll give you a few options that I know of from personal experience:

1. Forget cross-compiling and using QEMU `chroot` into the environment and build there. This is the easiest option.
2. Get all the required libraries on your host machine (outside of the sysroot) and compile using them - You just have to make sure that you have the exact same libraries as the target machine. Your toolchain file would be then reconfigured to look for libraries among the ones here.
   **EDIT: As @josch pointed out in the comments under his answer I should expand on this point to make it more clear to users.** However because he already mentioned the most important steps to take when applying this, I will refer the reader to his answer. I will however provide a **[link to debians official HowTo regarding Multi-arch](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO)**
3. The other option would mean fixing your projects CMakeLists to more adapt to the cross-compiling. This would require you to specify the absolute paths to the correct libraries. There is a drawback as you need to always *point* to the newest library. You could for example create another `.cmake` file that helps you configure the correct paths and because `target_link_libraries()` allows you to specify absolute paths, you could use the newly created custom targets.
4. The last option would be to fix the symlinks **(ideally by making them relative)**. This is in my opinion the preferred way. In the end the rootfs that you will be using for building will be just that, i.e. **used for building.**

As far as I know (I might be wrong here) but the `mks-build` is just a debian tool that is originally used for packaging `.deb` files and as such wasn't made to be complimentary to `CMake`. And if it was then the `debian` team probably has the toolchain files you are looking for (i.e. I would look for cross-compiling and package guides regarding `.deb` packages - if they exist they will be included).

---

`CMAKE_SYSROOT`, `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` only add a prefix to specific `find_` commands/functions. They pretty much can't change anything about the target system or the **linker behavior** (which is the issue here). Which means they are correctly configured. It's the `fake system` that is wrongly configured.

Comment: Hmm, was afraid that would be the case. Haven't been able to find anything about cross-compiling with Debian yet though. Still, thanks a lot for this thorough write-up!

Comment: @Xaldew it is a pain, I would try and check anything related to debian packaging. [For example here](https://wiki.debian.org/CrossCompiling). I know it was a topic some time ago to include CMake into the process (for cross-compiling as well). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! If anyone else comes across this, I've started a thread on the debian-cross mailing list: https://lists.debian.org/debian-cross/2023/02/msg00000.html

Answer (score 2):

You [wrote to the debian-cross mailing list](https://lists.debian.org/debian-cross/2023/02/msg00000.html) so I assume that your question is Debian specific? If so, maybe tag your question as such. Here is how you cross compile any Debian package for amd64 (aarch64) using `sbuild`:

```
sbuild --host=arm64 your_package.dsc
```

`sbuild` will take care of setting up your chroot as required and call the build tools with the correct arguments. You do not even need to create a special build chroot for that and can just re-use your existing chroots (sbuild will know what to do with them).

If instead, you just want to cross-compile some software using CMake on Debian, the process is as simple as installing a cross-compiler and pointing CMake to it:

```
$ sudo apt install g++-aarch64-linux-gnu
$ cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=aarch64-linux-gnu-g++ .
$ make VERBOSE=1
...
/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++ -rdynamic CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o -o main
...
$ file main
main: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 ...
```

That's it. No need for a sysroot.

If you haven't set up arm64 as a foreign architecture on your system, you need to run this once:

```
dpkg --add-architecture arm64
apt-get update
```

Comment: You will need to store compiled libraries if you build upon them more complicated applications. This is where the idea of a sysroot comes from. This is good if you build only using system libraries. But if you build library B, install it and in application A you wish to link it then having such environment makes it easier. What you write here is mentioned in the 2. point of my answer.

Comment: @MilanŠ. maybe you can extend point 2 of your answer to explain how what you write can be achieved in practice? That would make your answer more complete because currently "Get all the required libraries on your host machine (outside of the sysroot) and compile using them" is pretty non-descriptive for somebody who does not know about multiarch.

Comment: good point, but considering you already wrote the main step here, then I believe it's pointless to duplicate it. Secondly judging by the way the question was asked I didn't believe it was needed and I also believe that it would require another paragraph or so and that it is most likely answered somewhere else. EDIT: TL;DR: Laziness is my biggest weakpoint

Comment: Finally had a chance to try these things; and obviously there were some complications. At least on Ubuntu, you need to do this as well: https://askubuntu.com/questions/430705/how-to-use-apt-get-to-download-multi-arch-library?noredirect=1&lq=1
May be worthwhile to add a link to this in the answer.

Comment: I've also expanded the 2nd point as you suggested, considering that this topic is still discussed here.

Comment: I can now also confirm that the multiarch packages can be found and compiled in a much larger project. I should note though that it is important to set the `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` and `PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE` to appropriate values (`/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu` and `aarch64-linux-gnu-pkg-config` in my case).

Comment: can you show an example where you think you must use `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` you should not need that. Yes, setting `PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE` should be done as well if you want cross-pkg-config.